# Undefined control sequence in equation - error message but code works

Tags: errors, equations

When writing equations in my document, I get the same error message for all the equations. The code compiles, but the error messages pile up. The only thing that changes in the errors is the line it is refering to (in this example line 404).

Equation example:

```
\begin{equation}
    a
\end{equation}
```

Error message:

```
Undefined control sequence

<argument> ...es \theequation \unskip \italiccorr 
                                                  )
l.404 \end{equation}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: we need some more informations: document class, packages and, of course, a complete short example which shows the behaviour.

Comment: This aint be enough ... ;-) Looks a like a wrong `tag` format etc. But this is a guess only